# Image saving in database as C:\wamp64\tmp\phpAE1C.tmp instead of saving in public/images

Tags: laravel, image, file-upload, upload, edit

I am trying to edit/update an image in a user table, when I select a new image and submit the form the image name doesn't get stored in the database instead this C:\wamp64\tmp\phpAE1C.tmp get saved in the image column, I don't know why, Please help if u know why.

**The UsersController**

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|string|max:225',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.auth()->id(),
        'password' => 'sometimes|nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
    ]);

    $user = auth()->user();

    //Handle avatar Upload
        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            // Get filename with extention 
            $filenamewithExt = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just Extention
            $extention = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $filenameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extention;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('avatar')->storeAs('public/avatars', $filenameToStore);

        }

        if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            
            $user->avatar = $filenameToStore;
      
           
        }

        //Handle image Upload

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            // Get filename with extention 
            $ImageNameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $ImageName = pathinfo($ImageNameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just Extention
            $Extentions = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $ImageNameToStore = $ImageName.'_'.time().'.'.$Extentions;
            // Upload Image
            $paths = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images', $ImageNameToStore);
    
        }
    
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            
            $user->image = $ImageNameToStore;

            
        }
        
        $user->save();
    
    $input = $request->except('password', 'password_confirmation');

    if (!$request->filled('password')) {
        $user->fill($input)->save();

        return back()->with('success', 'Profile updated successfully!');
    }
    
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->fill($input)->save();
    
    return back()->with('success', 'Profile and password updated successfully');
}
```

**The image input field in edit.blade**

```
 <div class="form-group col-md">
        
        <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" >
        <label class="custom-file-label text-align-left" style="text-align:left;" 
        for="customFile">Choose file</label>
        </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Image saved correctly on your directory?

Comment: I think you shouldn't specify "public" as part of the path. The third argument to `storeAs()` method is the disk name. Also what is `$user->password = bcrypt($request->password);`??? Don't do this. Use the `Hash` facade.

Comment: @sta no the image is not saved in the directory

Comment: By default file system use your default disk named 'local' that upload files in storage/app folder store using store, stroeAs etc

Comment: @sta okay will use the hash but I used the public as part of the path in storing the avatar image which works fine, and also when creating a user for registration I used public/images and is also working fine!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change this :

```
$input = $request->except('password', 'password_confirmation');
```

to,

```
$input = $request->except('password', 'password_confirmation','image','avatar');

if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
      $input['image'] = $ImageNameToStore;
}

if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
      $input['avatar'] = $filenameToStore;
}
```

When using `fill` or `update` to persist Request data, it's always better to exclude the image fields. For any uploaded images in the request data it doesn't make much sense to store raw image data in database.

Rather the image can be stored on either local disk or something like S3 and the `path` to the saved image should be stored in database corresponding to the image field like avatar

Comment: I think you have it right, but it might be good to explain why to make this change. Also maybe improve their code so they aren't saving multiple times!

Comment: okay I just checked the public/images directory and the image was saved but the image name still saved as C:\wamp64\tmp\phpAE1C.tmp in the image column

Comment: Okay I will try your suggestion, Thank you

Comment: @miken32 the change is when user wants to edit their profile page info which also has an image that they uploaded during registration, so when they wish to change the image they initially uploaded the can do that. suggestion by sta worked for me but I am a learner if there is another way to do it I will appreciate it if you share it with me. thank you

Comment: Whenever there are image fields in the `$request` its always better to exclude those fields when using `fill` or `update` method and instead use the `path` to the saved file. One thing I know is that with ajax request the images/files are received as binary format and doesn't make sense to store the raw image data in a database - @miken32

Comment: I'm well aware of that @Donkarnash. But that info should be in the answer for future visitors.

Comment: @miken32 Yes I agree